# Replacing a string with file using sed, without using two sed commands?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, posix

In the process of automating a license header, I have a place holder: `/* @@LICENSE_HEADER@@ */`, which I can replace with a file named `license` with the following:

```
sh-3.2$ sed -e $'/\/\* @@LICENSE_HEADER@@ \*\//{r license\n}' \
-e $'/\/\* @@LICENSE_HEADER@@ \*\//d' file.c
```

I've cobbled this together from other sources. Is it possible to *replace* the string, rather than issuing a second command to delete the line the string appears in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `sed -e $'/\/\* @@LICENSE_HEADER@@ \*\//{r license\n;d;}' file.c`

Answer (score 0):

Sed is sort of a programming language for editing, so you can use more than one command per line.

By the way, I suggest you change the license string to something that doesn't contain any special regular expression characters. Here, I just made it `@@@LICENSE NUMBER@@@`, so I don't have to keep escaping the regular expression characters. After all, it's **your** string, so you can make it anything you want:

```
sed  '/@@@LICENSE NUMBER@@@/ {
r license.txt
d
}' file.c
```

Comment: It exists as a *comment* in C code, so the `/* ... */` form is necessary. Will sed have a problem with `@@` in the string otherwise?

Comment: Of course! It's `file.c`! (head slap!). You can still have the `/*...*/` in `file.c`, but not put them in sed's regular expression. The `@` are pretty safe. They have no special meaning in regular expressions. I'll add an example to my answer.